# Roblox Studio Text to Player

Tags: roblox

```
local text = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TextLabel
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer

while true do
    text.Text = game.player.playerVariables.Time.Value
end
```

Im trying to change the text of the label based off a variable that is stored in the player called time but it does not work. Please help

Answer (score 0):

For as far as I know there is no variable called time in the player, I get an error when I try to get it.

In my understanding what you want to do is to get the time that the player has been ingame and write that to a gui. What you can do is use the `time()` function to get the time that the player has been in the game.

---

There was also another small mistake in your code:

Your variable text was referencing the wrong thing,
`local text = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.TextLabel` references the textlabel in the startergui folder and not the one in the actual live player.

---

If I had to get the time the player was ingame and write that to a gui I would do it like this:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players") 
local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local textLabel = player:WaitForChild('PlayerGui'):WaitForChild('ScreenGui').TextLabel

while true do 
    textLabel.Text = math.round(time())
    wait(1)
end
```

This uses the `WaitForChild()` function to get the elements within the local player and you can then change the text in the gui in the localplayer.